# TS abstract class - cannot read property 'routes' of undefined

Tags: typescript, express

I'm building a server with express.js and typescript, I have abstract class `Controller` that is a base class for all controllers, and I have class `AuthController` that handles auth logic. When I make a post request to the server, I get an error, here it is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at setRoutes (C:\path\to\project\dist\typings\Controller.js:12:34)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    ...
```

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                   
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "outDir": "./dist",                        
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,                           
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Abstract controller class:

```
export default abstract class Controller {
    public router: Router = Router();
    public abstract path: string;
    protected abstract routes: Array<IRoute> = [];

    public setRoutes(): Router {
        for (const route of this.routes) {
            for (const mw of route.localMiddleware) {
                this.router.use(route.path, mw)
            };
            switch (route.method) {
                case 'GET':
                    this.router.get(route.path, route.controller);
                    break;
                case 'POST':
                    this.router.post(route.path, route.controller);
                    console.log('set to post')
                    break;
                case 'PUT':
                    this.router.put(route.path, route.controller);
                    break;
                case 'DELETE':
                    this.router.delete(route.path, route.controller);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('not a valid method')
                    break;
            };
        };

        return this.router;
    }
};
```

Route interface:

```
export interface IRoute {
    path: string;
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
    controller: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>;
    localMiddleware: ((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void)[]
};
```

Auth controller class:

```
export default class AuthController extends Controller {
    public path = '/';
    readonly routes: IRoute[] = [
        {
            path: '/login',
            method: 'POST',
            controller: this.handleLogin,
            localMiddleware: []
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            method: 'POST',
            controller: this.handleRegister,
            localMiddleware: []
        }
    ];

    constructor() {
        super();
    };

    async handleLogin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
        // some logic
    };

    async handleRegister(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
        // some logic
    };
}
```

I do this to use routes in Server class:

```
public loadControllers(controllers: Array<Controller>): void {
    controllers.forEach(controller => {
        this.app.use(controller.path, controller.setRoutes);
    });
};
```

And then initialize them in app.ts like this :

```
const controllers: Array<Controller> = [
    new AuthController(),
    new MatchmakingController(),
];
server.loadControllers(controllers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `loadControllers` function, you bind `setRoutes` method as callback of an express handler. You don't know when and **who** will call the callback function, in normally context (who calls express handler function) is `undefined`, this is reason `this.routes` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined` error.

I think we have 2 ways to solve that issue:

1. Binding `this context` for `setRoutes` method (I recommended): `loadControllers` function.

```
this.app.use(controller.path, controller.setRoutes.bind(controller)); // binding controller as `this`
```

2. Use arrow function to "fix" this keyword scope: Abstract controller class

```
public setRoutes = (): Router => { // Now, setRoutes is a property
    // method content
    // Now, "this" alway is this controller
}
```